# winston logstash udp connections handleing

Tags: node.js, logstash, syslog, winston

I am using Winston log-stash package for my Nodejs services (syslog udp).
While i was testing my app i saw that my docker containers opens lots of connections to the firewall before the log-stash server.
In large scale testing, 3 of my docker containers made more than 80,000 connections at the same time.

My Nodejs services are RestApi (express), run in debug mode and writes lots of logs per request.

How Winston log-stash handle udp log-stash connections,
How can i manage them?
If Winston log-stash opens connection per request, how should I design my code in order keep writing large amount of logs per request?

thanks :)